# Does Selenium IDE send data externally when it exports/converts tests to another language? (e.g. c#)

Tags: c#, export, selenium-ide

I would like to be able to use Selenium IDE at work, but I need to be able to provide reassurance that there isn't a security risk when exporting recorded test scripts to another language.

I need to know which of the following it does:

a) converts from the recorded Selenium IDE test case (table format) to another coding language internally and generates the converted code.

b) sends the recorded Selenium IDE test case to an external server, which generates the converted code and sends it back.

I've checked the [documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/code-export/) and searched their blog. Also searched here and did a more general Google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this confirmed by selenium-users@googlegroups.com group - no, it does not send the information externally. Answering in case anyone else needs it - this is the confirmation I got.

---

Nothing is sent from Selenium IDE to any server what-so-ever, the code is also opensource and the build is reproducible so you can check it yourself!

Selenium IDE does the conversion locally, as a whole we do not collect any data, and even if we did we would be very upfront, and will always give the option to opt out completely, that being said some pointers to look out for:

1. We do not control what the browser does, and do not know if Google or Mozilla are collecting anything, but I'm assuming you are fine recording on them, which means that its a risk you are willing to take.
2. When installing plugins to Selenium IDE, we also do not control what data they use, take extra caution when installing plugins from sources you do not know.
3. Be sure to apply this safety to other browser extensions you have installed, since they are running side-by-side with the IDE, they too can access the same web pages as the IDE can.